# How can I track clicks on app post if I have Authenticated Referrals enabled?

Tags: facebook, analytics, facebook-opengraph, facebook-authentication

1. my Canvas App has Authenticated Referrals enabled
2. my Canvas App post on user's wall
3. when user's friend clicks on that post facebook auth dialog appears as popup with "Go to App" and "Close"

Is there a way to track the click on that post?

*(we use mixpanel as analytics)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Your app
3. Insights
4. Installs